# UICollectionView not sized or rotating properly

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I tried translating Apple's CollectionView-Simple demo app from Objective-C to Swift 1.2 using Xcode 6.3 and a fresh project. It's not working right. Specifically, the view does not size itself properly when rotating the device. It also has sizing issues in portrait mode that are different for iPhone 5s and iPad 2.

I've hunted through the storyboard for differences and can't find the issue. I don't know what the relevant code to post is, so I have the whole thing up on GitHub:

https://github.com/DavidSteuber/CollViewSwift

Does anyone see the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: Please add the problematic code, see [this](http://sscce.org) article to see how to properly display code for us to help you with. Stating “I don’t know what the relevant code to post is” won’t help you. If you do not know how to find the problematic code please search help on how to debug, otherwise do the debugging and see what the problematic code is. Nobody here will help you if you need to look through a whole xCode project.

Comment: I'm sorry I threw the whole smack out here. I really lost any hope of finding the problem or even narrowing down the code to something useable. I was getting desperate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the `autoresizingMask` in your Storyboard.  I replaced your CollectionViewController with a fresh one, and it worked as expected.  Looking at the source code for the two view controllers, only 1 difference jumped out:

**Your collection view controller:**

```
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
```

**New collection view controller:**

```
<autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
```

---

I'm not sure how this happened (perhaps you used an old Storyboard?), but you can fix it in one of three ways.

1. <kbd>Control</kbd>-click on `Main.storyboard` in the *Project Navigator* and select `Open As->Source Code`.  Then change `flexibleMaxX` to `widthSizable` and change `flexibleMaxY` to `heightSizable`.  Save the file, and then <kbd>Control</kbd>-click on `Main.storyboard` in the *Project Navigator* and select `Open As->Interface Builder - Storyboard` to put it back.
2. Instead, you could just recreate the Collection View Controller from scratch as I did.
3. Finally, you can also fix this problem in code.  You can add this method to your your main `ViewController`:

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       self.collectionView!.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I actually used a fresh project, although I did have some trouble with the root view relationship. I need to read up on that some more. I have no idea how the autoresizingMask got messed up. I continued to search for the issue after submitting here (that really was a last resort). I did not spot any such options in the visual version of the storyboard editor. Attempts in the past to mess with the XML have resulted in crashes, so I'm leery to go there.